# Transforming array using JavaScript ES6 iterators

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How can I transform employees array variable to departments array variable using javascript es6 iterators functions? I am looking for an efficient solution.

**From:**

```
var employees = [
    { name: 'John', department: 'Digital Experience' },
    { name: 'Doe', department: 'Digital Transformation' },
    { name: 'Symon', department: 'Digital Planning' },
    { name: 'Joey', department: 'Digital Experience' },
    { name: 'Abul', department: 'Digital Experience' },
    { name: 'Smith', department: 'Digital Experience' },
    { name: 'Ajad', department: 'Digital Transformation' },
    { name: 'Rahim', department: 'Digital Transformation' },
    { name: 'Luke', department: 'Digital Planning' },
];
```

**To:**

```
var departments = [
        {
            department: 'Digital Experience',
            employeeNames: ['Johm', 'Joey', 'Abul', 'Smith']
        },
        {
            department: 'Digital Transformation',
            employeeNames: ['Doe', 'Ajad', 'Rahim']
        },
        {
            department: 'Digital Planning',
            employeeNames: ['Symon', 'Luke']
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Is there any inefficient code which you tried?

Comment: Why iterators? Why not just a reduce operation?

Comment: This is perfect use case for reduce. why not reduce ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there's other ways, this seems reasonably short though.

```js
var e = [
    { name: 'John', department: 'Digital Experience' },
    { name: 'Doe', department: 'Digital Transformation' },
    { name: 'Symon', department: 'Digital Planning' },
    { name: 'Joey', department: 'Digital Experience' },
    { name: 'Abul', department: 'Digital Experience' },
    { name: 'Smith', department: 'Digital Experience' },
    { name: 'Ajad', department: 'Digital Transformation' },
    { name: 'Rahim', department: 'Digital Transformation' },
    { name: 'Luke', department: 'Digital Planning' },
];

const departments = [...new Set(e.map(x => x.department))].map(y => {
  return {
    department: y,
    employeeNames: e.filter(z => z.department === y).map(w => w.name)
  }
})

console.log(departments)
```